# Maintaining session in Facebook Api

Tags: facebook, api, cookies, authentication

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK to login and register.
The code is sth like this:

require_once('facebook/facebook.php');

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'id',
    'secret' => 'secret',
    'cookie' => true,
));
```

$user = $facebook->getUser();

```
if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = NULL;
    }
}

if ($user) {
    $_SESSION["logout_url"] = $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl( array(
                   'scope' => 'offline_access, publish_stream, email',
                   )); 

    $_SESSION["userprofile"] = $user_profile;


    header("Location: $index");

}
else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                   'scope' => 'offline_access, publish_stream, email',
                   )); 

    header("Location: $loginUrl");
}
```

When you login and turn off and on again web browser Facebook Session is lost, so I add an JS script like this:

```
   FB.init({
     appId  : 'id',
     status : true, 
     cookie : true, 
     xfbml  : true  
   });
```

Which should solve my problem with cookies. But now, if you login for the second time script creates infinity loop of redirects and site can't be loaded.
After this I need to restar app_secret_id and cut out JS code to be able to login again.